# String.split won't let me split with periods

Tags: java, split

I am trying to do a `String.split` on a website address using the `"."` so that I can find the domain name of the website.

However, when I do this:

```java
String href = "www.google.com";
String split[] = href.split(".");
int splitLength = split.length;
```

It tells me that the `splitLength` variable is `0`. Why is this, and how can I make this work?

Comment: If only there was some source of documentation for these method, amiright?

Comment: lol, that's exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find before tho. Must have used the wrong search terms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this to split the string:

```
href.split("\\.");
```

Explanation: `split` splits on a regex, not on a regular substring. In regexes, `.` is the metacharacter for 'match any character', which we don't want. So we have to escape it using a backslash `\`. But `\` is also a metacharacter for escaping in Java strings, so we need to escape it twice.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think this one works!

Comment: Added an explanation to your answer.

Comment: You are always welcome to add some good work :)

Answer (score 4):

[Split uses a regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) so do:

```
String split[] = href.split("\\.");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already. It tells me that it's an illegal escape character during compile-time